# Error devise don't generate factory with factory_bot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, factory-bot

I'm using rails 5.1.4
devise 4.4.1
factory_bot_rails 4.8.2

```
rails g devise User
Running via Spring preloader in process 15889
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20180213152941_devise_create_users.rb
      create    app/models/user.rb
      invoke    rspec
      create      spec/models/user_spec.rb
       error      factory_bot_rails [not found]
      insert    app/models/user.rb
       route  devise_for :users
```

Comment: Devise just invokes the rails model-generator if the model does not exist already. So this does not seem a devise error, but an error with factory-bot-rails? Does it work when generating any other model?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for replay, the problem was that in config/application.rb, fixture_replacement need to pass :factory_bot and not factory_bot_rails, reading the doc I see that are distinct gems.